# Unselect unknown selectable

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, selectable

I have a table thats devided logically in 2 halves. I will have to select only half of a row as in the image.
[image]

Now if I choose a different "half" row, I need to deselect the previous one. How would I do that? My code is here:

```
<tr class="line1">
    <td width="10" class="td3523" onclick="selectme('3523');">
        <input type="radio" name="selattendance" id="tr3523" onClick="setEditDelete(3523)"/>
    </td>
    <td width="100" class="td3523" onclick="selectme('3523');">2012-11-19</td>
    <td width="125" class="td3523" onclick="selectme('3523');">
        <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border: 0;padding: 0;border-collapse: collapse">
            <tr> 
                <td style="width: 50%;padding-right: 10px;border: 0" align="right" valign="middle">22:54</td>
                <td style="width: 20%;border: 0">     <a href="#" onclick="loadPic('attendanceimages/39286a0a6b45cae9f116b11882f36046.jpg','2012-11-19','2012-11-19','add','','In','22:54:04','22:54:04');"><img src="images/punchimg.png"></a>
                </td>
                <td style="width: 20%;border: 0">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </td>
</tr>
```

When I click on any `td`, all `td`s with the same ID get selected using this code:

```
function selectme(id) {
    $('.td' + id).toggleClass("ui-selected");
}
```

I guess I need to put another line removing this class from previously selected `td`s. How would I do that? Thanks.

Comment: Can you create a http://jsfiddle.net/ for it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Give your `<td>`-s another class say `tdclss` then use it in your function to remove `ui-selected` class.

```
function selectme(id) {
  $('.tdclss').removeClass("ui-selected");
  $('.td' + id).toggleClass("ui-selected");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

One approach:

```
$('input:radio').change(
    function(){
        // caching the jQuery $(this) object
        var that = $(this);
            that
                // moves up to the closest ancestor table element
                .closest('table')
                // finds the '.selected' elements within that table
                .find('.selected')
                // removes the 'selected' class from those elements.
                .removeClass('selected');
            that
                // moves to the parent td element
                .parent()
                // selects subsequent siblings *until* it finds
                // an element that matches the selector
                .nextUntil($('td:has("input:radio")'))
                // adds back the current td element to the collection
                .andSelf()
                // adds the 'selected' class
                .addClass('selected');
    });​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/f6Pe4/1/).​

References:

- [`addClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/).
- [`andSelf()`](http://api.jquery.com/andSelf/).
- [`closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/).
- [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/).
- [`:has()` selector](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/).
- [`nextUntil()`](http://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/).
- [`parents()`](http://api.jquery.com/parents/).

Comment: That would've been a great answer except that I need to click on any where on the row not only the checkbox. Thanks for your answer

Answer (score -1):

Using several fields with the same ID is asking for trouble sooner or later. You can use class attributes to group the cells, or you can (probably) use a `<span>` to group them (although I must admit, I have never tried a `<span>` within a `<tr>`).